# How to write a recursive function that calculates the net worth of coins after some years?

Tags: python

I have a working code, although there's something I can't wrap my head around.

```
def stonks(coins, rate, years):
    """
    Each year your crypto-investment grows.

    Write a recursive function that calculates the net worth of coins after some years.
    Rate is in percents.
    Round the answer down to the nearest integer.

    stonks(1000, 10, 10) -> 2593
    stonks(100000, 12, 3) -> 140492

    :param coins: starting amount (0-100000)
    :param rate: starting amount (0-100)
    :param years: starting amount (0-50)
    :return: coins after years
    """
    if years is not 0:
        return stonks((coins * (1 + rate / 100)), rate, years - 1)
    else:
        return coins
```

Expected output:

```
print(stonks(1000, 10, 10))  # -> 2593
print(stonks(100000, 12, 3))  # -> 140492
```

My output:

```
print(stonks(1000, 10, 10))  # -> 2593.742460100001
print(stonks(100000, 12, 3))  # -> 140492.80000000005
```

If I add math.floor(coins * (1 + rate / 100)) -> My output:

```
print(stonks(1000, 10, 10))  # -> 2591 --- incorrect, needs to be 2593.
print(stonks(100000, 12, 3))  # -> 140492 --- correct
```

How is it possible, one of the outputs is floored correctly from 140492.80000000005 to 140492, but the other output 2593.742460100001 is floored incorrectly to 2591?

Is it due to the recursion count being larger and thus the math.floor applies on every event of recursion thus rendering the final output off?

Comment: I would guess because it’s done for every recursion instead of just the last one. Try wrapping the `floor` function around the initial call to the `stonks` function.

Comment: wow, that seemed to do the trick, thank you very much, if only I could choose a comment as best answer haha!

Comment: It’s alright, just glad you got it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `return stonks((coins * (1 + rate / 100)), rate, years - 1) // 1`